# invoking Print on Load

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have a page in Joomla that opens a pop up window after clicking a print button element.  Here is the script that runs the "public function render

```
    public function render($params = array()) {

    $params = $this->app->data->create($params);

    // include assets css
    $this->app->document->addStylesheet('elements:itemprint/assets/css/itemprint.css');

    if ($this->app->request->getBool('print', 0)) {

        // Hide respond form from the printing view
        $this->app->document->addStyleDeclaration('#comments #respond { display:none; }');

        // Hide comments if requested
        if (!$params->get('showcomments', true)) {
            $this->app->document->addStyleDeclaration('#comments { display:none; }');
        }

        return '<a class="element-print-button" onclick="window.print(); return false;" href="#"></a>';
        /*return '<a class="element-print-button" window.onload="window.print();" href="#"></a>';*/
```

Notice the element-print-button.  Currently it is set to print on click I want it to print on load instead.  I am not able to insert the onload function into a body tag because this page is created on the fly with the $params = array

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
return '<a class="element-print-button" onclick="window.print(); return false;" href="#"></a><script>window.onload=window.print();</script>';
```

DISCLAIMER: I don't know how Joomla works, but this is just a Javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to insert the onload function into a body tag

Then you could use a `<script>` block with

```
window.onload = function() { … }
```

instead.

But doesn’t Joomla incorporate and advanced JS library like f.e. jQuery or something already? Those should provide methods to execute code onload or ready without having to rely on an oldschool approach like event handlers via HTML attributes …